# Generic Implementation of Directed Graph

Tags: java, generics

I am having issues in implementing the Generic DirectGraph Implementation. Please help me!

```
public interface DirectedGraph<Vertex<T extends Comparable<T>>> {
   <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean  addVertex(Vertex<T> v);
   <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean addEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);
   int size();
   <T extends Comparable<T>>boolean removeEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);
   <T extends Comparable<T>>boolean hasEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);

}

public class Vertex<E extends Comparable<E>> {
  E vertex;
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?. Eclipse is showing the error

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "<", , expected
- The type parameter Vertex is hiding the type 
 Vertex<E>
- Syntax error on token ">>>", >> expected
```

Comment: Which issues are you having exactly? Does this code compile?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that something was wrong with the above code?

Comment: Nope! .. The code is not compiling. Eclipse is showing the error

    Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "<", , expected
 - The type parameter Vertex is hiding the type 
  Vertex<E>
 - Syntax error on token ">>>", >> expected

Comment: @PraveenReddyKatta That's a step in the right direction, given that we can't see your monitor. Now edit your post to include it, properly formatted, instead of pasting it into a comment. Please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Good; you did the right thing by editing your question to add the information. Now, we do not know what "this line" is. Please clearly identify the line that Eclipse is referring to. Please remember that we cannot see your screen.

Comment: public interface DirectedGraph<Vertex<T extends Comparable<T>>>

This is the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you make a class generic or a method generic.In your case,you are doing both.Also,since you have decided that `DirectedGraph` will use `Vertex` type,it is not the class Vertex but **type** **"Vertex"**.You use a concrete class or interface type when you use the class or generic method **and not in the definiton itself**

```
public interface DirectedGraph<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        boolean  addVertex(Vertex<T> v);
        boolean addEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);
        int size();
        boolean removeEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);
        boolean hasEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2);

    }

    class Vertex<E extends Comparable<E>> {
      E vertex;
    }
```

Comment: How can I restrict the DirectedGraph to accept only of Type Vertex??.. because the change you made would accept Any type that implements Comparable ... correct??. Please explain!

Comment: @PraveenReddyKatta You have alreay restricted.The type T is the type which wil be substituted for the type "E" of vertex

Comment: @PraveenReddyKatta All your method parameters are taking Vertex type